# A difficult Trigonometrical Equation

Tags: trigonometry

Hi everyone I have this question on a trigonometry exercise:

We are given that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{12})= \frac{\sqrt 6-\sqrt 2}{4}$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{12})= \frac{\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2}{4}$ and we are asked to prove it satisfies the equation $$\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sin (x)}+\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\cos (x)}=4\sqrt2$$ Then we are asked to find the other solution between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I found out by using the calculator that the other solution is $\frac{11\pi}{36}$, but I can't explain it without the graph and calculator.

Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}$ in for $\sin x$, then substitute $\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}$ in for $\cos x$.  Now, we are left with $$\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\frac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}}+\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4}}$$.  Now, this simplifies to $$\frac{4\sqrt3-4}{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}+\frac{4\sqrt3+4}{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}$$ Now, we multiply the left side (numerator and denominator) by the conjugate of $\sqrt6-2$ which is $\sqrt6+2$ and we multiply the right side by the conjugate $\sqrt6+2$. When we multiply and simplify we get $\frac{16\sqrt2}{4}$ which simplifies to $4\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your equation as 
$$(\sqrt 3-1)\cos x + (\sqrt 3 +1)\sin x = 2\sqrt 2 \sin 2x$$
You already know that $\sin \frac {\pi}{12} = \frac{\sqrt 6-\sqrt 2}{4} = \frac{\sqrt 3 - 1}{ 2\sqrt 2}$ and $\cos \frac {\pi}{12} = \frac{\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2}{4} = \frac{\sqrt 3 + 1}{ 2\sqrt 2}$, so now you can write your equation as
$$\sin \frac {\pi}{12}\cos x + \cos \frac {\pi}{12}\sin x = \sin 2x,$$
hence
$$\sin \left(\frac {\pi}{12}+x\right)=\sin 2x.$$
The formula of difference of $\sin$ gives you
$$0=2\sin \left(\frac 12 \left(2x - x - \frac{\pi}{12}\right)\right)\cos \left(\frac 12 \left(2x + x + \frac{\pi}{12}\right)\right) = $$
$$=2\sin \left(\frac 12 \left( x   - \frac{\pi}{12}\right)\right)\cos \left(\frac 12 \left(3x  + \frac{\pi}{12}\right)\right),$$which yields you all possible solutions.